# CUDADeviceCount is 0 on Mathematica 11.3 and Paclet 11.3.82

Tags: cudalink, paclets

I am Normi.

I am using Mathematica 11.3 and trying to use CUDA Kernel on Windows 10.
My Graphic Cards

1. NVIDIA Tesla K20c (it is not in the list of supported GPU. But it has Tesla K20 in the list)
2. NVIDIA Quadro K4000 (it is in the list of supported GPU)

I have tried following commands

```
Unprotect["`*"]
ClearAll["`*"]
Needs["CUDALink`"]
```

`CUDAQ[]` gives `True` (sometimes it is `False`, I don't know why)

`CUDAResourcesInstall[]` gives `{Paclet|CUDAResources,11.3.82,<>|}}`

```
CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]
PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSite[]
```

But `$CUDADeviceCounts` gives `0`

I have tried to run CUDADot:

```
A = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}];
B = RandomReal[1, {2, 2}];
CUDADot[A,B]
```

which gives error

```
CUDADot::init: CUDA failed to initialize. Refer to CUDALink System 
Requirements for system requirements.
```

Please help, thank you

editted: the problem is solved. I have downloaded CUDA 9.1. I refer to this website http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html which says paclet 11.8.32 needs CUDA 9.1

Comment: `Unprotect["\`*"]` should never be necessary, is questionable at best, and dangerous at works. That likely isn't affecting your GPU issues, but I'd avoid it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @user6014

Comment: In Googling I found this: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/41293. Is it helpful?

Comment: thank you again. i will check it @user6014

Comment: the problem is solved. I have downloaded CUDA 9.1. I refer to this website http://www.wolfram.com/CUDA/CUDAResources.html which says paclet 11.8.32 needs CUDA 9.1